# Is there any assertable terminal "emulator" preferable for NodeJS or .NET?

Tags: node.js, testing, terminal, console, ansi-escape

I am currently in the process of writing a logging library for NodeJS. This logging library is based on ANSI codes written to the terminal for moving the cursor around and clearing text and more. I would like to write tests for that library that are kind of like integration tests where I would execute the library with a few examples and then assert if the console output looks as expected.

Now I know that I can simply redirect the output for example to a string, but I would have to handle all the special ANSI keywords myself, including remembering the cursor position and so on.

I am wondering if anyone knows about some sort of terminal that allows for the currently actually displayed text to be read/asserted. It can very much also be a completely mocked terminal with no UI, or even a string output that simulates all the ANSI stuff.

If it doesn't exist, I guess I'll write it myself, but I would prefer not to reinvent the wheel here ^^
Also if you have other suggestions on how to test this library, feel free to comment anyway :)

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: seems like u are reinventing the wheel while making that logging library. you can check out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/terminal-kit

Comment: @AritraChakraborty That's why I said "here" ^^ I know there are tons of logging libraries and I went through many of the more popular ones, but none are perfect for my use-cases. Also, I am always doing those things to learn stuff and develop new skills.